# iOS Safari input type text partially loses focus after element resize

Tags: javascript, html, input, mobile-safari

I have an Input Element type='text' which gets into a buggy state in iOS Safari, such that the input element appears focused and dispatches keyup events but does not update the value of the field; no new characters are visible as the user types. In a website I am building I trigger this state after resizing** a focused text input element***. I have made a jsfiddle which reliably reproduces the bug:

```
<input id='ipt' type='text' style='width:250px;height40px;'/> 

<script>
  var ipt = document.getElementById('ipt');
  ipt.addEventListener("keyup", onkeyup, false);
  function onkeyup(e){
    ipt.style.width = '100px';  
    ipt.removeEventListener("keyup", onkeyup, false);
  }
</script>
```

To reproduce the bug:

1. Open http://jsfiddle.net/55dth/embedded/result in iOS Safari
2. Focus the input element with a tap
3. Pinch zoom to show the full width of the input (necessary to trigger bug)
4. Type something

I would like to understand why it is getting into this buggy state, and how I might be able to avoid it. It may well involve being in an iframe and the document settings. I have to be in an iframe, and I need to change the width of the text field.

Or how to get out of this state. I can detect that I am in the state, by listening for keyup and checking the value at the insertion point compared with the key value in the event. I tried toggling readonly, resetting the value, focus(), toggling inputmode...

---

** I want to resize the element - so that there is more horizontal space to type when the keyboard is up.

*** I am pretty sure that other conditions are necessary to get into this state, however I am not sure of the exact conditions.

Comment: I have the same problem, the caret is out of bounds when container changes it's height, have you able to fix this?

Comment: Similar issue here.  it does not want to give the element focus through  clicks, I can give the input element focus pro-grammatically though.